# Using ampersand for struct and asterisk for Go

Tags: go

Two questions on below code that I saw during youtube tutorial for Go.

Trying to read this code and I see that slice of pointer struct being assign to productList... Ok, that's good but why ampersand for Product? (I understand that is address of). I understand struct does get tagged with ampersand when you want to pass to function (since it is pass by value by default) but even that I understand if receiver is pointer, you do not need to use ampersand.. So why use the ampersand here?

```
 type Product struct {
    ID int
    name string
}

var productList = []*Product{
    &Product{
        ID: 1,
        Name: "Latte",
    },
    &Product{
        ID: 2,
        Name: "Ice Coffee",
    },
}
```

Another words, what's the difference between above and below?

```
var productList = []*Product{
    Product{
        ID: 1,
        Name: "Latte",
    },
    Product{
        ID: 2,
        Name: "Ice Coffee",
    },
}
```

Comment: "&" means pointer of value, "*" means need the address of pointer. see this example 
https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1

Comment: *but even that I understand if receiver is pointer, you do not need to use amerpsand.. So why use the amerpsand here??* <-- What does this mean?

Comment: can you please just explain why after saying Product is pointer, also need to add ampersand to Product ?

Comment: I also updated the example

Comment: @user3502374: Your question is unclear, you are referring to function, it is not in your input code shown. What is your actual question?

Comment: The 2nd example isn't valid because, your type is a slice of `*Product` types. Remember slice of pointer to `Product` and _not_ slice of `Product` struct instances. How to create a pointer to `Product` - use the `&`. The second case won't even compile

Comment: @user3502374 you know you can omit the type of the *elements* of a slice literal altogether, right? i.e. `var productList = []*Product{{ID:1,Name:"..."}, {ID:2,Name:"..."}}`.

Comment: @user3502374 "So why use the amerpsand here??" Because the ampersand evaluates to a pointer, without the ampersand, i.e. just `Product{...}`, the element value ain't a poitner, and since the slice literal specifies the element's type as a pointer that is what you need to give it. It's like asking *"why use double quotes in the following code `[]string{"foo", "bar"}`? why not `[]string{foo, bar}`"*, the answer to that is because `foo` is not a `string` but `"foo"` is. (unless, of course, `foo` is a variable that contains a string then that's ok)

Comment: For method calls the address and dereference operators are inserted automatically: https://tour.golang.org/methods/6 ff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var productList = []*Product
```

means that `productList` is a list of pointers. Each pointer points to a `Product`.

If you do

```
var productList = []*Product{
    Product{
        ID: 1,
        Name: "Latte",
    }
}
```

you are initializing `productList` with a list of things of type `Product` instead of a list of things of type pointer to `Product` (which is illegal and will raise a Compile Time Error saying "Cannot use Product literal (type Product) as type *Product in slice literal).